# How do you echo out the in_array result?

Tags: php, arrays

I am trying to each out the matching airport code value. I.e. if it matches HKG, it will echo Hong Kong.

```
$city  = array (
            'HKG'=>'Hong Kong',
            'SIN'=>'Singapore',
            'TPE'=>'Taipei',
            'HND'=>'Tokyo',
            'MDW'=>'Chicago',
         );

if(in_array($city, $row->city)){
    echo 
}
```

Comment: in_array checks *values*, not keys. You want `isset($city[$row->city])`. Also, you had the arguments the wrong way around for in_array anyway.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Why not just use

```
echo $city[$row->city];
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are getting result, just use

```
echo $row->city;
```

Comment: That would only echo out the shortcode name for the city, EG: HKG, SIN, TPE. Not the whole name.